# Flatten and reshaping input to an encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have dataset containing 3D fixed length segments shaped `(1,200,4)` which I would like to feed in to an Antoencoder with fully connected layers, similar to:

```
 encoder
autoencoder.add(Dense(200, input_shape=(self.input_dim,), activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(self.input_dim,), activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(80, input_shape=(self.input_dim,), activation='linear'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(encoding_dim, input_shape=(self.input_dim,), activation='linear')) 
        
#decoder
autoencoder.add(Dense(80, activation='linear')) 
autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) 
autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(self.input_dim, activation='linear'))
```

I know this input need be flatten before fed in to this network, I would be expected to add a `Flatten()` layer just before the first `Dense()` of the encoder.

What I not sure of, is a way to reconstruct the input back to its own shape `(1,200,4)` at the decoder part.

If it matters, the input consists of a numpy-ndarray of fixed-length segments, such that:

```
print(train_x.shape)
(140508, 1, 200, 4)
```

For example, let say the input is this:

```
X = np.random.randn(3400, 1, 200, 4)


X.shape
(3400, 1, 200, 4)
```

I how do I apply a flatten layer to this input at encoder and then reconstruct it at the decoder for a fully-connected autoencoder similar to above.

Any suggestion about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a possibility... you need to simply take care or dimensionality in the end and operate a proper reshape

```
encoding_dim = 20
input_shape = (1,200,4)
n_sample = 100

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,) + input_shape)

autoencoder = Sequential()

autoencoder.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')) 
        
#decoder
autoencoder.add(Dense(80, activation='relu')) 
autoencoder.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) 
autoencoder.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))  
autoencoder.add(Dense(np.prod(input_shape), activation='linear'))
autoencoder.add(Reshape(input_shape))

print(autoencoder.summary())
autoencoder.compile('adam', 'mse')
autoencoder.fit(X,X, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It really helps.